# How to get total favorite count of a particular follower?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, rtweet

I want to find how many tweets of user A did their specific follower B favorited. Is there any way to do this using either Python's `tweepy` or R's `rtweet`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it is a bit complicated.

You need to use [`GET favorites/list`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-favorites-list)

This will let you get up to 200 Tweets that User B has liked.  You would then have to search through the returned Tweets to see which ones were posted by User A.

The [Tweepy documentation for favorites](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.8.0/api.html#favorite-methods) tells you how to do this:

```
tweets = API.favorites("edent")
```

Will get you all the tweets I've liked.

Comment: Since it returns only 200 tweets that user B has liked, would that mean there would potentially be false negatives - i.e., it is quite likely that we may not get any of the tweets of user A that user B has liked?

Comment: That's correct. You can paginate through the Tweets using Tweepy. But there may be some missing.